# HLS spec omits "FRAME-RATE" attribute from EXT-X-STREAM-INF M3U8 tag between drafts 15 and 16, why?

Tags: http-live-streaming, m3u8, m3u

The most recent HTTP Live Streaming spec (16) omits the FRAME-RATE attribute from the  EXT-X-STREAM-INF tag.

The link following shows the diff of the two latest versions of the spec (drafts 15 and 16):

- draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-15.txt
- draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-16.txt

[https://www.ietf.org/rfcdiff?url1=draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-15&url2=draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-16]

See that in section 4.3.4.2. "EXT-X-STREAM-INF" the FRAME-RATE attribute is present in 15 but not in 16. But there was no mention of why it was omitted. Is it now deprecated? Can it still be used? Should players ignore it if a FRAME-RATE attribute is specified? What if my playlist uses the FRAME-RATE attribute, can it still be used or will I need to change my playlists and remove it?

Answer (score 1):

Since I was curious about this too I contacted the draft author and he kindly provided the information.

The `EXT-X-STREAM-INF` optional attribute `FRAME-RATE` **is not** deprecated/removed but it was published by mistake before being fully validated.

It is now so we can expect it to return in a future version of the protocol. It will be used to allow devices that don't support higher framerates to skip the respective streams without the need to fetch a media segment beforehand.

For now:

To support forward compatibility, when parsing Playlists, Clients
   MUST:

- ignore any unrecognized tags.
- ignore any Attribute/value pair with an unrecognized
    AttributeName.
- ignore any tag containing an attribute/value pair of type
    enumerated-string whose AttributeName is recognized but whose
    AttributeValue is not recognized, unless the definition of the
    attribute says otherwise.